# Recurrence relations question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

A vending machine dispensing books of stamps accepts only one-dollar coins, $1 bills, and $5 bills.

a) Find a recurrence relation for the number of ways to deposit $n$ dollars in the vending machine, where the order in which the coins and bills are deposited matters.

b) What are the initial conditions ?

c) How many ways are there to deposit $10 for a book of stamps ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you deposit $n$\$ you either :

- deposit 1\$ coin, and then deposit $n-1$\$
- deposit 1\$ bill, and then deposit $n-1$\$
- deposit 5\$ bill, and then deposit $n-5$\$ (if $n\ge 5$)

Hence $$f_n=2f_{n-1}+f_{n-5} $$

Initial condition : $f_0=1$ (one way to deposit nothing, by doing nothing).

\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
n&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\
f_n&1&2&4&8&16&33&68&140&288&592&1217\\
\end{array}

Comment: Thank you Xoff :). Do you have any tips for me when i approach these kind of problems ? I'm not good at discrete math.

Comment: Just try to think about the different choices you have. Try to find them all (here there are only 3 choices), and use that to find the recurrence relation.

Comment: Okay good, Thank you :)

Comment: very well explained...